# integral over product of two bessel functions at discontinuity

Tags: special-functions, improper-integrals, bessel-functions

The Weber-Schafheitlin integral

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{J_{\mu}(a t)J_{\nu}(bt)}{ t^{\lambda}}\;dt
$$

where $J_{\mu}(x)$'s are Bessel functions of the first kind, can have delta function singularities at $a=b$, for instance for $\mu=\nu$ and $\lambda=-1$. Is there a formula for the delta function singularities for general $\mu, \nu, \lambda$? A formula I found in Watson's "Treatise on Theory of Bessel functions" gives an expression in terms of gamma functions,

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{J_{\mu}(a t)J_{\nu}(at)}{ t^{\lambda}}\;dt=\frac{a^{\lambda-1}\Gamma(\lambda)\Gamma((-\lambda+\mu+\nu+1)/2)} {2^{\lambda} \Gamma((\lambda+\mu-\nu+1)/2)\Gamma((\lambda+\mu+\nu+1)/2)\Gamma((\lambda-\mu+\nu+1)/2)}
$$

but this does not yield the delta functions singularities (but rather are finite) for values of $\lambda$ outside the specified radius of convergence $\lambda>0$, as can be checked for the $\mu=\nu$, $\lambda=-1$ case.

Comment: I think you can find interesting the fact that when $\lambda=1$ the integral equals the sum of the values of the integrand function over the natural numbers, as shown here: http://rsc.anu.edu.au/~pgill/papers/159_Bessel.pdf